# How to pass file as parameter from Azure logic apps and receive it in Azure function?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-logic-apps

I am able to pass parameters and values from logic apps to Azure function. But I am wondering how could I pass file as parameter and receive it in Azure function?

A snippet of how I am passing parameter from Azure logic apps:

[image]

In Azure function to receive simple parameter and its value:

```
public static async Task<object> Run(HttpRequestMessage req, TraceWriter log)
{
    string jsonContent = await req.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    dynamic data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(jsonContent);
    string dateValue = data.fileName;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that the function will be receiving a JSON payload, a couple options are:

1. If the file content is small you can read it and send it along in
   the body as a simple string property (e.g. `{ fileName: '...',
   content: '...' }`)
2. Send along only the path to the file contents (e.g. a blob path or
   an Azure Files path) and read the file contents in your function.